# Why typescript conditional type is able to define type more strict?

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following examples:

```
type CanDefineConverterParamType<T, U extends keyof T = keyof T> = U extends any
  ? {
      field: U;
      converter: (value: T[U]) => any;
    }
  : never;

const xx: CanDefineConverterParamType<typeof testObj> = {
  field: 'one',
  converter: (value) => {},
  // value type is string
};

type CannotDefineConverterParamType<T, U extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  field: U;
  converter: (value: T[U]) => any;
};

const yy: CannotDefineConverterParamType<typeof testObj> = {
  field: 'one',
  converter: (value) => {},
  // value type is string | number
};
```

Why in this example using conditional type without any other changes the type is able to define type of generic parameter "U" more precisely?

```
type SomeType<T = string, U = number> = T extends any
  ? U extends any
    ? {
        x: T;
        y: U;
      }
    : never
  : never;
const someFn = <T extends string = string, U extends number = number>(
  obj: SomeType<T, U>
): SomeType<T, U> => {
  return obj;
};
const someResult = someFn({ x: '2', y: 2 });
// {
//   x: string;
//   y: number;
// }

type SomeType2<T = string, U = number> = {
  x: T;
  y: U;
};

const someFn2 = <T extends string = string, U extends number = number>(
  obj: SomeType2<T, U>
): SomeType2<T, U> => {
  return obj;
};
const someResult2 = someFn2({ x: '2', y: 2 });
// SomeType2<"2", 2>
```

And here why in someResult2 the return type is different? Also when we try to assign someResult2.x = "something" we get an error, while in someResult.x = "something" we do not.

Why conditional type is working like that?

Playground:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-75cw7f

Comment: This seems to be something to do with [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) - if I replace `T extends any ? U extends any ? ...` with `[T] extends [any] ? [U] extends [any] ? ...` then you get the stricter type. I'm not sure specifically why it being a distributive conditional type affects it, but perhaps this will help address the issue and perhaps it will help someone else come up with an answer.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK76KW) capture enough of your problem to investigate? It helps to provide a [mre], with emphasis on "minimal" so that the issue is as easy to locate as possible.  If that example captures your problem, please consider changing the code in your question to match.  If not, what is it missing?

Comment: Assuming I understand the question correctly, I have not been able to find an answer by researching GitHub issues or docs.  The problem seems to be that type parameters don't get inferred as "non-widening literal types" (as implemented in [ms/TS#24310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24310)) when the inference site is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  But I have not found any relevant prior discussions about this. Possibly someone might want to open a GitHub issue to ask?